# Is there a memcache server ported to windows but *not* the couchbase version

Tags: windows, memcached

I have scoured stack overflow and references and references to references but I cannot find the above - all roads seem to lead to couchbase. I'm sure their product is great but I am in a situation where I will (potentially) be using a windows box as a memcache server in a commercial environment.

Is anyone aware of a compiled version of memcached running on windows ? I don't mind; either 32 or 64 bit.

Please do not close this as "possible duplicate of the following" and link to a similar question where the answers are just either links to membase.org, couchbase or sites that are supposed to list memcache installations but in reality just link to those previous sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is Memcached 1.4.5 (32 & 64) [here](http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows)

And use the wrapper for service [here](https://github.com/eric-b/MemcachedService64)

Only drawback with the Wrapper is that it will create a new tmp file for the service which you will have to allow on your firewall at every reboot...